# Как собрать freeDOS

Tags: linux, gcc, build, archlinux, freedos

Мне нужно собрать freeDOS из под linux (arch). Я перепробывал все методы, но не нашел как это сделать.

Все идет нормально, пока не появляется ошибка

```
ia16-elf-gcc -c -I. -I../hdr -DFORSYS -DWITHFAT32 -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -fpack-struct -fcall-used-es -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -Wno-pragmas -Wno-array-bounds -Werror -o sys.obj sys.c
make[1]: ia16-elf-gcc: Нет такого файла или каталога
make[1]: *** [GNUmakefile:65: sys.obj] Ошибка 127
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/user/OS/freedos/sys»
make: *** [makefile:116: all] Ошибка 2
```

Я обыскал все, но не нашел `ia16-elf-gcc`

Comment: Ха, так вам надо его самому собрать из сорцов, не должно быть долго.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tkchia/build-ia16
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-ia16-elf
```

Подробнее тут: [https://launchpad.net/~tkchia/+archive/ubuntu/build-ia16/](https://launchpad.net/%7Etkchia/+archive/ubuntu/build-ia16/)

Comment: А на arch Linux нет?

Comment: @Very_cool_programmier Чего нет? На arch другой пакетный менеджер?  Но смысл остаётся один: добавьте репозитарий  ppa:tkchia/build-ia16, обновите локальный кэш и установите пакет.

Comment: @Very_cool_programmier, руками из сорцов соберите — быстрее будет. А отвечающему: там другой пакетный менеджер и формат пакетов, так что не в тему ваш комментарий.